# How can I select all child elements except one and its descendants?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to select all the elements in my container except for a particular child element and its descendants.

In the following example I want `My name is Donald` and `I am a duck` to be excluded by the jQuery that highlights everything else in the `container` div.

The issue is that the selector `.container :not(.intro)` seems to only exclude `My name is Donald`. Is there a way to do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container :not(.intro)").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="intro">My name is Donald
    <div>I am a duck</div>
  </div>
  <div>I live in Duckburg.</div>
  <div>My best friend is Mickey.</div>

</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/urbycoz/rq398f5y/)

Comment: I disagree with this question being closed as a duplicate. The other question is entitled "What is the difference between '>' and a space in CSS selectors?" How can you find that question unless you already know the answer to mine?

Comment: *How can you find that question unless you already know the answer to mine?* --> this is the purpose of the duplicate. I know the answer so I can find that question. By knowing the difference and the existance of such selector you have your answer. As a side note, we don't close a question only based on the title

Comment: Ok, so it's not so much a "duplicate" as covering the same topic from a slightly different angle? I realise you don't close questions based on the title, but I was making the point that the question is explaining the concept I didn't know existed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `>` between `.container` and `:not(.intro)` This will result in that it will only select direct children of `.container` that don't have the class `.intro`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container > :not(.intro)").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container > :not(.intro)").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="intro">My name is Donald
    <div>I am a duck</div>
  </div>
  <div>I live in Duckburg.</div>
  <div>My best friend is Mickey.</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Damn you guys are good. Thanks!

Comment: @Urbycoz No problem, happy to help.